# locate imports definition in java

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in java. Is there any way to find the required imports(or missing imports) in java programming?. I know that in modern editor like Eclipse and Netbeans. But we have to do java in notepad  for examination, that's why.

For example, When I use Jframe, I want to know which is the required imports. Is it possible to locate 'import's definition in a directory or file?

Comment: you will get exception with that class name which is not found

Comment: It seems kind of strange to me that you want to develop in a notepad. Anyway youre best bet is to google which package contains the class you want to use.

Comment: It's isn't possible at exam time bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the compiler `javac` which tells you the types that cannot be resolved (this imports are missing).

Then you can use the javadoc from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). In the left lower corner there is a complete list of classes in the API. Search the class and click on it then you know in which package it is.

Comment: For anyone regularly perusing any JavaDoc, I *strongly* suggest using the [javadoc-search-frame](https://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/). It's available for Firefox and Google Chrome and makes browsing JavaDoc much easier.